# attempt to de-reference null object when using maps to build parent-child relationship for visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, map, null

Products Products__c

| Name | Label | Data Type | Sample Data | Sample Data 2 | Sample Data 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PDC | PDC__c | Text | ACA | ACG | TBC |
| PDC Desc | PDC_Desc__c | Text | Tire Size | Rim / Wheel Disc Size | Type of Toolbox |
| Value Desc | Value_Desc__c | Text | 255/70R 22.5 | 22.5x8.25 | None |
| Prod Order | Prod_Order__c | Lookup | a1C2f000001jCyYEAU | a1C2f000001jCyYEAU | a1C2f000001jCyYEAU |

Product Groups Products_Groups__c

| Name | Label | Type | Sample Data | Sample Data 2 | Sample Data 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product Code | Product_Code__c | Text | ACA | ACG | TBC |
| Product Group | Product_Group__c | Text | Tires / Wheels / Hubs and Drums | Tires / Wheels / Hubs and Drums | Tool Boxes |
| Product Group Seq | Product_Group_Seq__c | Number | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| Product Seq | Product_Seq__c | Number | 1 | 2 | 5 |

Desired VFP Results based on sample data. Sorted first by Product_Group_Seq__c then Product_Seq__c:

| Tires / Wheels / Hubs and Drums |  |
| --- | --- |
| Tire Size | 255/70R 22.5 |
| Rim / Wheel Disc Size | 22.5x8.25 |

| Tool Boxes |  |
| --- | --- |
| Type of Toolbox | None |

Below is my standard controller.

I am trying to get this into a parent-child map format where I can display on visualforce page with the `Product_Group__c` from `Product_Groups__c` being a header value showing all `Product_Code__c` and their child value `Value_Desc__c` from `Products__c` below in repeating format.

I am receiving attempt to de-reference null object

and I can see in debug it says AdjacentGroup|null

> 11:07:44:377 EXCEPTION_THROWN [23]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

```java
public with sharing class Productsv2Controller {
    
    public String OrderId {get;set;}
    public Map<String, Products_Groups__c> groupsMap {get;set;}
    public Productsv2Controller() {
        
        OrderId = ' ';
        
        OrderId=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
        
        System.debug('...................OrderId=='+OrderId);
        
        Id i= Id.valueOf(OrderId);
        
        Map<String, Products_Groups__c> groupsMap = new Map<String, Products_Groups__c>();
        for(Products_Groups__c og :[SELECT Id,Name, Product_Code__c,Product_Group_Seq__c,Product_Group__c,Product_Priority_Level__c,Product_Seq__c FROM Products_Groups__c]){
            groupsMap.put(og.Product_Code__c, og);
        }
        
        for(Products__c o :[SELECT Id,PDC__c, PDC_Desc__c, Value_Desc__c from Products__c WHERE Prod_Order__c = :i]){
            Products_Groups__c adjacentGroup = groupsMap.get(o.PDC__c);
            
            system.debug('Group: '+adjacentGroup.Product_Group__c+' Code: '+adjacentGroup.Product_Code__c+' PDC: '+o.PDC__c+' Value: '+o.Value_Desc__c);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clearly indicate which line hits this error. If you **[edit]** your post to include a stack trace, there will be less guesswork involved for those interested in helping you.

Comment: I will add stack trace. Is that the dump of the debug log? I apologize, I am very new to this and have been tossed in.

Comment: @Wes The stack trace is the part of the error that tells you what classes/methods have been called (and on what line). Each method that gets called puts information onto "the stack" (a Computer Science concept) that tells the program where to return after the current method is done executing (among other things). In this case, I suspect it'd only be one or two additional lines, with `Productsv2Controller.constructor: line 23, column 1` or something to that effect on the top of the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restructure this controller to use an inner class (sometimes called a wrapper class so your data model is easier to handle in the VF page

```
public inherited sharing class Productsv2Controller {
    
    public String orderId { // orderId lazy loader
       get {
         if (orderId == null) {
            orderId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
         } set;
    }

    // inner class that represents the parent-children for a single parent
    public class ProductGroup { 
       public Products_Groups__c pg {get; private set;}
       public List<Product2> products {get; private set;}

       ProductGroup withProductGroup(Products_Groups__c val) {this.pg = val; return this;}
       ProductGroup withProducts(Products__c[] val) {this.products = val; return this;}
    }

    // Map used by VF page to display all parents and children
    public Map<String, ProductGroup> productGroupsByProductCode {
       get {
          if (productGroupsByProductCode == null) { // lazy load

            // Pivot order's Products__c by PDC
            productGroupsByProductCode = new Map<String,ProductGroup>();
            Map<String,Products__c[]> productsByPDC = new Map<String,Products__c[]>();
            
            for(Products__c p :[SELECT Id,PDC__c, PDC_Desc__c, Value_Desc__c 
                                  FROM Products__c WHERE Prod_Order__c = :this.orderId]) {
                String pdcLower = p.Pdc__c.toLowerCase();
                if (!productsByPDC.containsKey(pdcLower)) {
                  productsByPDC.put(pdcLower,new List<Products__c>())
                }
                productsByPDC.get(pdcLower).add(p); // build list
            }

            // Construct the parent-child
            for (Products_Groups__c pg: [SELECT Id, Product_Code__c, ...
                                            FROM Products_Groups__c]
                                            ) {
                productGroupsByProductCode.put(pg.Product_Code__c, new ProductGroup()
                  .withProductGroup(pg)
                  .withProducts(productsByPDC.containsKey(pg.Product_Code__c.toLowerCase()
                    ? productsByPDC.get(pg.Product_Code__c.toLowerCase())
                    : new List<Products__c>());                                
            }

          }
       } private set;
    }
    public Productsv2Controller() {}
        
        
}
```

VF markup (based on [VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm)) snippet

```
<apex:repeat value="{!productGroupsByProductCode}" var="productCode">
   <apex:outputText value="{!productGroupsByProductCode[productCode].pg.XXX__c}"/>
   
   <apex:repeat value="{!productGroupsByProductCode[productCode].products" var="prod">
      <apex:outputText value="{!prod.PDC_Desc__c}"/> // or whatever field(s) you want from Products__c object
   </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Some notes

1. SObject names with plurals are a really bad idea. If this is *de novo* development, I'd really encourage you to singularize the SObject names
2. I renamed your variables and changed to camelCase
3. The inner class uses a fluent pattern (sometimes called a builder pattern) to set its properties. This is not strictly necessary but useful to learn for a variety of reasons
4. Everything is done with collections which is a good way to avoid NPE;
5. I agree with Derek's advice about map keys which are case sensitive
6. VF controllers should ideally have empty or near empty constructors and where all the logic is either in properties/methods referenced by the page's merge fields or page action methods for `action="{!doSomething}` on the page.
7. I didn't test this so YMMV

Comment: Thanks for all the help @cropredy. I was able to use the above to get my map and list. I am still struggling to iterate through it appropriately. I am trying to use apex repeat as follows. Am I going about this the correct way? `<apex:repeat value="{!productGroupsByProductCode}" var="pKey">
                <apex:repeat value="{!pKey}" var = "pKey2">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!productGroupsByProductCode[oKey2]}" /><br/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat>`

Comment: I added the VF markup

Comment: I appreciate you adding that markup. I can see I was a little bit off in my understanding of how to access the values. I attached an example of the visualforce table I am tryign to build in my original post. I am trying to group codes under their respective group as shown. Is that possible with the map you have helped/provided?

Comment: yes ... (assuming the map is built as I expected - you can see by a system.debug) that is what I more or less provided without the CSS - my suggestion is to create a new question that includes just the inner class and map, the VF markup you have, the desired result, and what the VF markup currently generates. No need to include how the map is built or the rest of the controller as that will just clutter the question

Answer (score 4):

When you run into an NPE (Null Pointer Exception), you *always* have something in your code that partially evaluates to `null.<something else>`. `null` is a special type/value thing. It has no variables or methods (instance or static), so when Salesforce encounters `null.<something else>` execution cannot continue and you get an exception.

Line 23 for you is

```
system.debug('Group: '+adjacentGroup.Product_Group__c+' Code: '+adjacentGroup.Product_Code__c+' PDC: '+o.PDC__c+' Value: '+o.Value_Desc__c);
```

So either `adjacentGroup` is null, or `o` is null.

`o` cannot be null because it's being fed from a query, and queries never return null objects. If your query returned no rows, the rest of your for loop would not be executed.

So `adjacentGroup` must be null. That variable is set from the result of `groupsMap.get(o.PDC__c)`. The issue you're running into is that the value of `o.PDC__c` does not exist in your map.

We don't have enough information to tell you much beyond that. Whatever your `PDC__c` value is does not exactly match any of the `Product_Code__c` values from the `Product_Group__c` records you queried.

While most things in Apex are case-insensitive, Sets and the keys of Maps are the two biggest exceptions. Both of them are extremely case-sensitive, so "prodcode_123" and "PRodCOde_123" are different in this context.

Comment: _extremely_ case sensitive :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed assistance Derek. Is there a simple way to handle this null error when manually building this parent-child map? I expect that I will have many adjacentGroup.Product_Group__c in which the product code is not on the o.PDC__c. The Product_Group__c object stores all the PDC__c and their group. So it will return many more attributes than were likely selected.

Comment: @Wes Again, there's not enough context here (and the field names are opaque) so I can't give targeted advice. One general principle you could use here is **check to see if something is null before you try to use it**. `if(adjacentGroup == null){ continue; }` as the second line in your final for loop would avoid the issue (`continue;` causes you to skip the rest of the loop for the current iteration and start processing the next record). Whether or not that's what you actually want to do, I can't say, but it is _a way_ to deal with it.